# Batch Renaming in Linux

Tags: bash

I have a folder with 50+ files in it. The format for the file names is
"name space - space designation . extension.

How would a command to copy these reversing the name and designation for each file be worded?

Opensuse 12.3 x64 KDE

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of a file before and after renaming?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to like something like so:

```
for orig in *\ -\ *.*; do
    BASE=${orig%.*}
    EXT=${orig##*.}
    NS=${BASE% - *}
    SD=${BASE#* - }
    echo mv "$orig" "$SD - $NS.$EXT"
done
```

and remove the `echo` if it looks right (a la @V-X 's "remove the |bash")

`man bash` and scroll to the "Parameter Expansion" section.

Comment: (note that even though the "echo" won't show it, this will properly quote the arguments and "mv" will see exactly 2)

Answer (score 1):

The rename command is good here:

```
$> ls ./*txt
./foo - bar.txt  ./foo.txt

$> rename -nv 's/(\w*) - (\w*)/$2 - $1/' ./*txt
./foo - bar.txt renamed as ./bar - foo.txt
```

The `n` stops the command from actually renaming the files so you can try as many regexes as you want before you finally try the rename.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that name or designation doesn't contain neither `.` nor `-`.

I usually do this by something like `ls -la | awk '{fn1=$10; split(fn1, file_ext, "."); split(file_ext[1], name_designation, " - "); fn2=name_designation[2] " - " name_designation[1] "." file_ext[2]; print "mv " fn1 " " fn2 }' | bash`

I know, this is not a nice solution, but it works ( with the limitation above).

Comment: before trying, remove the | bash at the end, to see, if all the commands are ok.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have files:

```
name - designation.extension
```

and you want:

```
designation - name.extension
```

? (keeping the space; as you didn't mention taking them off)

then:

```
find /some/path -name '* - *.*' -print | sed -e 's/^\(.*\) - \(.*\)\.\([^\.]*\)$/mv "&" "\2 - \1.\3"/' > script_to_rename.sh
```

and if the script_to_rename.sh looks fine,

```
.  ./script_to_rename.sh
```

to execute it

Comment: this assumes quite a lot of things (for once, that you don't have ' - ' in /some/path at all... and other things like this. BE CAREFUL)